# Creating a simple class in python for doing simulation of MDP

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, python, scheduling, markov-decision-process, reinforcement-learning

I am currently learning Python and doing object-oriented programming. I am trying to create a simulation for MDP.

My problem statement is: "I have four stages of process. Each stage has two equipment items. Each equipment item is associated with doing a certain task".

I am trying to formulate Class in Python for stage, equipment item, production task and so on.

Ex:

```
class Stage:
def __init__(self, equipment: EquipmentItem):

    self.equipment = equipment
```

```
    class EquipmentItem:
    def __init__(self, tasks: List[ProductionTask] ):

        self.tasks = tasks
```

Each stage has two equipment items.

Comment: It would be helpful, if you could provide us a formalization of the state space of the MDP. Also, this [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-deep-dive-into-problem-states-498ad0746c98) might help you in understanding what a state space is.

Comment: What does this have to do with MIP?